# package.json Not Found after using npm audit fix

Tags: json, npm, sass, node-modules, node-sass

I am trying to install sass and I don't understand why I keep running into the issue shown below[image: the screenshot of the error is as shown in the first image]

I understand I should follow the instructions and run `npm audit fix` but when I run the command, I get an error of `no package.json found`, and yes, that is so because sass wasn't installed at all and thus no node-modules and the json file, how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `npm init` command at the root of your project to generate the `package.json` file and re run the command to install sass.